# Validating version number using regex for user input

Tags: ruby, validation, version

I need to validate version numbers, e.g., `6.0.2`/`6.0.2.011` when a user enters them. 
I checked `to_i`, but it doesn't serve my purpose. What can be a way to validate the version number? Can anyone let me know?

Comment: What would you like to do is not clear still to me..

Comment: @Arup. I am trying to validate a version number when a user inputs it on program execution. So when I enter 6.0.2.011 it should validate that it doesnt have any special characters/characters other than integer and `.`

Comment: Can you show your code.. why do you think that your one is not working? Which might help us to help you out..

Comment: its just a simple code. i am looking for how to validate a "Version Number" 

`version_num = gets`
when i run this ruby script, I will be asked to enter the version number.. So after I enter the version number I need to validate it before going ahead with next step

Comment: -1. Question entirely not clear. Define a valid version number. Is `.1` valid? Is `2.1.` valid? Is `2.x` valid? Is `2.0-beta` valid? Is `10000000.1.6` valid?

Comment: @sawa. Valid versions in my case are `1.1`/`1.1.1`/`1.1.11`/`1.1.1.111`

Comment: Here's an important concept to keep in mind: version "numbers" are not numbers, they are strings, containing numerical values separated by periods and other non-numerics, and don't necessarily follow a consistent spec or pattern. You might need a lot of different code to validate version numbers from different companies or products.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a regular expression that matches a "valid" version number as per your specifications (only numbers separated by `.`):

```
/\A\d+(?:\.\d+)*\z/
```

This expression can be broken down as follows:

```
\A        anchor the expression to the start of the string
\d+       match one or more digit character ([0-9])
(?:       begin a non-capturing group
  \.      match a literal dot (.) character
  \d+     match one or more digit character
)*        end the group, and allow it to repeat 0 or more times
\z        anchor the expression to the end of the string
```

This expression will only allow `.` when followed by at least one more number, but will allow any number of "sections" of the version number (ie. `6`, `6.0`, `6.0.2`, and `6.0.2.011` will all match).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with version numbers, I advise the `versionomy` ([Github](https://github.com/dazuma/versionomy)) gem.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps.

```
if a.length == a.scan(/\d|\./).length
  # only dots and numbers are present
  # do something
else
  # do something else
end
```

e.g

```
a = '6.0.2.011' 
a.length == a.scan(/\d|\./).length #=> true

b = '6b.0.2+2.011'
b.length == b.scan(/\d|\./).length #=> false
```

input length is checked against the scan outcome's length to ensure only dot and numbers are present. Having said that, it is very hard to guarantee that future version numbers will all follow the same conventions. How will you make sure that some one does not introduce something like `6a.0.2.011`

Comment: `a.length` - 10 
and `a.scan(/\d|\./).length` - 9 for the same inputs `a= '6.0.2.011'` 
why is it so ?